# Matching URLs in text except those enclosed by square brackets

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex so I can identify URLs in text.

Possible (likely) Test cases:

- **http://a.url.com**
- **http://a.url.co.uk**
- [http://a.url.com]
- [http://a.url.co.uk]
- [ http://a.url.com]
- [ http://a.url.co.uk]
- [http://a.url.com ]
- [http://a.url.co.uk ]
- [ http://a.url.com ]
- [ http://a.url.co.uk ]
- text here **http://a.url.com** and here
- text here **http://a.url.co.uk** and here
- text here [http://a.url.com] and here
- text here [http://a.url.co.uk] and
  here
- text here [ http://a.url.com] and
  here
- text here [ http://a.url.co.uk] and
  here
- text here [http://a.url.com ] and
  here
- text here [http://a.url.co.uk ] and
  here
- text here [ http://a.url.com ] and
  here
- text here [ http://a.url.co.uk ] and
  here

**Only the lines without square brackets should match. And only the URL should be matched, not the whole line.** In case it was unclear the bold text in the list above is what I would like the regex to match on.

The current regex I've worked out is:

```
(^|[^\[ ])(https?://\S+)
```

Only the first 2 lines match, I can't figure out how to make the other lines without the Square brackets match?

I've used groups because I'll be replacing the match with some HTML later. But need to get the regex working properly first.

I've been using this online tool to help me build and test the regex; http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use negative lookahead assertions to ensure the line does not contain square brackets using the regex:

```
^(?!.*\[.*\]).*(https?://\S+)
```

[Rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/9b9xtVb5QY)

Comment: Thanks, this helped lead to the regex I needed:
(?!.*[\[\]])(https?:\/\/\S+)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(?<=^[^\[\]]*)(https?://\S+)(?=[^\[\]]*$)
```

With `[^\[\]]*` you say that there could be any symbols except square brackets before and after your link.
This uses positive lookahead and lookbehind to check that there is no brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I pasted your regex in to the online regex tool; it matches the correct lines BUT it matches the whole line. I need to match just the URL portion in that line in a group, so that I can replace that URL with a HTML Hyperlink.

Comment: You can use groups for getting only the part of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your modified working regex:

```
([^\S\]](https?:\/\/[^\]\s]+)[^\S\]]|^(https?:\/\/[^\]\s]+)$)
```

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/9b9xtVb5QY)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not quite right. Your regex matches all the URLs in every line. I want to match the URLs only on the lines which do not have square brackets. See the bold line in the Question.